# How'd I determine where one packet ends and where another one starts

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

While sending packets across a network, how can one determine where one packet ends and where another starts?

Is sending/receiving acknowledgment one of the ways of doing so?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of packets or sockets? E.g. with TCP sockets you just have a datastream. You don't see where the packet boundaries were. With UDP socket, you receive one packet with recv(). Then SCTP protocol has SEQPACKET that is somewhat like a TCP stream, but retains the packet boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume here that you mean application-level 'packets'.

If you use UDP, you don't need to since it's a message protocol.  TCP is a byte streaming protocol, so it cannot send packets, just bytes.  If you need to send anything more complex than a byte-stream across TCP, you have to add another protocol on top - HTTP is one such protocol.  Text is fairly easy since lines have terminating characters, usually CR/LF/CRLF.  Sending non-text messages will require a different protocol.

One approach that is often used with TCP is to connect, stream a protocol-unit, disconnect.  This works OK, but slowly because of the huge latency of continually opening and closing TCP connections.  HTTP usually works like this in order to serve up web pages to large numbers of users who, if left permanently connected while they viewed pages, would needlessly use up all the server sockets.

Waiting for an application-level ACK from the peer is sometimes necessary if it absolutely essential that peer receipt is known before the next message is sent, but again, this is slow because of the connection latency.  TCP was not designed with this approach in mind.

If the commonly available IP protocols cannot directly provide what you need, you will have to resort to implementing your own.

What sort of 'packet' are you sending?

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

TCP is a stream-based protocol.  That is, it provides a stream vs. packet or message-based interface to the application.  If using TCP, an application must implement its own method of determining packets or messages.  For example, (a) all message are a fixed size, or (b) each message is prefixed with its subsequent size, or (c) there is a special "end-of-record" sequence in the data stream to indicate a message boundary.  Search google for lots of information on how one can implement message boundaries in TCP.

Answer (score 0):

With TCP sockets, you just see the datastream where you can receive and send bytes. You have no way of knowing where a packet ends and another begins.

This is a feature (and a problem) of TCP. Most people just **read data into a buffer until a linefeed (\n) is seen**. Then process the data and wait for the next line. If transferring chunks of binary data, one can first inform the receiver of how many bytes of data are coming.

If packet boundaries are important, you could use UDP but then the packet order might change or some packets might be lost on the way without you knowing.

The newer SCTP protocol behaves much like TCP (lost packets are resend, packet ordering is retained) but with SCTP sockets you can send packets so that receiver gets exactly the same packet.